# MySQL , fetch persons by operation register_date

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables..(MySQL)

PERSONS (person_id PRIMARY_KEY) and OPERATIONS(person_id FOREIGN_KEY).

[image]

[image]

I need to fetch person list where the period between each transaction is more than one year..

[![enter image description here][3]][3]

Example,  Jessy'a transactions are

```
2012-12-25  
               TIMEDIFF(op1.REGISTER_DATE,op1.REGISTER_DATE) > 1 YEAR(OK)
2015-01-11
               TIMEDIFF(op1.REGISTER_DATE,op1.REGISTER_DATE) < 1 YEAR 
2015-09-11
               TIMEDIFF(op1.REGISTER_DATE,op1.REGISTER_DATE) < 1 YEAR
2016-09-11
                TIMEDIFF(op1.REGISTER_DATE,op1.REGISTER_DATE) < 1 YEAR 
2016-01-11
                TIMEDIFF(op1.REGISTER_DATE,op1.REGISTER_DATE) < 1 YEAR 
2017-09-11
                TIMEDIFF(op1.REGISTER_DATE,op1.REGISTER_DATE) < 1 YEAR 
2017-08-11
                TIMEDIFF(op1.REGISTER_DATE,op1.REGISTER_DATE) < 1 YEAR 
2017-11-11
                TIMEDIFF(op1.REGISTER_DATE,op1.REGISTER_DATE) < 1 YEAR 
2017-01-11
```

if any TIMEDIFF > YEAR then add this person to my list , I need these persons..Please help..

Comment: StackOverflow is not a wishlist site. We will not write code for you just because you posted your request. We can can help solve [certain on-topic problems](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), but it's **your** job to **[put some efforts](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** on the subject in the first place, including elementary **[(re)search](https://google.com/)**.

Comment: Dear Marcin , it's not a wish.I've made enough effort.But, 
I couldn't do that.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like

```
select x from persons p 
   where not exists 
     (select o.id from operations o join operation o2 
      where o.person_id = p.id 
            and o2.person_id = p.id 
            and o.id != o2.id 
            and timediff(o.register_date, o2.register_date) < 1 year)
```

I just wanted to design the idea, timediff is something you have to look up, see how you can subtract timestamps and compare with time intervals.

Comment: Find persons with a 1 year and more difference between transactions

Comment: Exactly, which means (almost) all persons for which no 2 different operations exist, that are nearer than one year. 

You will find persons with a single operation as well. Do you not want these at all, or do you want to return these, if their operation is longer than 1 year from now? Anyway, one idea, how this can be achieved should be given.....

Answer (score 0):

in Oracle I try this...it's work..But in MySQL ?

```
SELECT  PERSON_ID FROM
(
SELECT 
op.PERSON_ID,
row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY op.PERSON_ID ORDER BY op.PERSON_ID) rownumber,
LEAD(op.REGISTER_DATE,1) over(PARTITION by op.PERSON_ID order by op.REGISTER_DATE),
MONTHS_BETWEEN(LEAD(op.REGISTER_DATE,1) over(PARTITION by op.PERSON_ID order by op.REGISTER_DATE),op.REGISTER_DATE)AS ferq
FROM operations op
)
WHERE ferq >= 12 AND rownumber = 1;
```